# How to draw a shapefile over GeoTIFF geometry to a PNG

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, c

How I can to draw using GDAL in python or c a polygon shapefile shape.shp with a GeoTIFF as background background.tiff file?

Both files are in the same projection.

The result could be a PNG, JPEG or whatever.  To clarify I'm going to put screen shoots of the done with QGIS. First one is the shapefile, second the GeoTIFF, and finally the union.

[image: Shapefile File]

[image: GeoTIFF file]

[image: GeoTIFF as background and shape as shadow]

Comment: Are you wanting this to be scripted, or a one time thing?

Comment: @AlecBennett scripted or c coded

Comment: Add alpha to the gdal_rasterize command as in here http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/176471/how-to-set-opacity-with-gdal-rasterize. There are other usable answers as well, search with "gdal_rasterize".

Comment: @user30184 It's look similar, I'm going to test it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to rasterize the shapefile using `gdal_rasterize`, and then overlay it onto the other raster file.

A similar question exists and is available here: [how to overlay shapefile and raster?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21888/how-to-overlay-shapefile-and-raster)